# Getting Facebook Instant Article formatted content from TinyMCE generated HTML

Tags: tinymce, facebook-instant-articles

I am using TinyMCE as CMS to create articles, and want to integrate it with Facebook Instant Articles.
How can I get IA formatted content for an article with all the validators and transformers applied?

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook Instant Article PHP SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/sdk